# XNA - Input string was not in correct format

Tags: c#, xna

For my load method, where I read in the sprites positions. When I run the game and Press 'L' to load, it says "Input message was not in correct format".

This is my whole code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace PickUpTheCrewGame
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class PickUpTheCrewGame : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        // states for the enums
        public enum State
        {
            Menu,
            Playing,
            Gameover,
        }

        //Setting the variables
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        SpriteFont messageFont;
        SpriteFont playerScoreFont;
        Texture2D backgroundTexture;
        Rectangle backgroundRectangle;
        Texture2D menuImageTexture;
        Rectangle menuImageRectange;
        Texture2D gameoverImageTexture;
        Rectangle gameoverImageRectangle;
        Sprite BlueBall;
        Sprite GreenBall;
        Sprite OrangeBall;
        Sprite PinkBall;
        Sprite RedBall;
        Sprite c;
        Sprite YellowBall;
        public Texture2D menuImage;
        public Texture2D gameoverImage;

        //---player scoresyer
        int playerScore = 0;
        int highScore = 0;

        //Lists
        List<sharks> sharks = new List<sharks>();
        List<Sprite> crew = new List<Sprite>();
        List<int> highscoreList = new List<int>();



        //Set First State
        State gameState = State.Menu;

        HUD hud = new HUD();

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for the PickUpTheCrew Game
        /// </summary>
        public PickUpTheCrewGame()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);

            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

            //sreen size
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1280;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 720;
            menuImage = null;
            gameoverImage = null;


        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
            //enable the mousepointer
            //IsMouseVisible = true;
            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Highscore method
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool IsHighScore()
        {
            if(playerScore >hud.highScore)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Writing the Save File
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filename"></param>
        public void Save(string filename)
        {
            System.IO.TextWriter textOut = null;
            try
            {
                textOut = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename);
                Save(textOut);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (textOut != null) textOut.Close();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Saving the information into the save file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="textOut"></param>
        private void Save(TextWriter textOut)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (Sprite crew1 in crew)
                {
                    textOut.WriteLine(crew1.location.X);
                    textOut.WriteLine(crew1.location.Y);
                }

                foreach (sharks enemySprite in sharks)
                {
                    textOut.WriteLine("Shark");
                    textOut.WriteLine(enemySprite.location.X);
                    textOut.WriteLine(enemySprite.location.Y);
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// This method loads the file from save document
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filename"></param>
        public void Load(string filename)
        {
            System.IO.TextReader textIn = null;
            //try
            //{
            textIn = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);
            Load(textIn);
            //}
            //catch (Exception e)
            //{
            //    throw e;
            //}
            //finally
            //{
            if (textIn != null) textIn.Close();
            //}
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Load method for the data in the file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="textIn"></param>
        private void Load(TextReader textIn)
        {
            foreach (Sprite crew1 in crew)
            {
                crew1.location.X = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
                crew1.location.Y = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
            }
            foreach (sharks enemySprite in sharks)
            {
                enemySprite.location.X = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
                enemySprite.location.Y = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
            }
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            hud.LoadContent(Content);

            //-----LOAD THE MENU BACKGROUND-----
            menuImageTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("menuImage");
            menuImageRectange = new Rectangle(0, 0,
                Window.ClientBounds.Width,
                Window.ClientBounds.Height);

            //------LOAD INGAME BACKGROUND-----
            backgroundTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Background");
            backgroundRectangle = new Rectangle(
             0, 0, // top left hand corner
             Window.ClientBounds.Width,
             Window.ClientBounds.Height); // size of screen display

            //GAMEOVER IMAGE BACKGROUND
            gameoverImageTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("gameoverImage");
            gameoverImageRectangle = new Rectangle(
                0, 0,
                Window.ClientBounds.Width,
                Window.ClientBounds.Height);


            //------- Loading in Captains crew-------

            c = new Sprite(new Vector2(400, 150), new Vector2(400, 150),
                  Content.Load<Texture2D>("WhiteBall"), Color.White);

            BlueBall = new Sprite(new Vector2(640, 450),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlueBall"));
            crew.Add(BlueBall);

            GreenBall = new Sprite(new Vector2(750, 200),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("GreenBall"));
            crew.Add(GreenBall);

            OrangeBall = new Sprite(new Vector2(115, 400),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("OrangeBall"));
            crew.Add(OrangeBall);

            RedBall = new Sprite(new Vector2(500, 600),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("RedBall"));
            crew.Add(RedBall);

            YellowBall = new Sprite(new Vector2(800, 400),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("YellowBall"));
            crew.Add(YellowBall);

            PinkBall = new Sprite(new Vector2(25, 175),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("PinkBall"));
            crew.Add(PinkBall);

            //--------Loading in the Sharks------
            sharks s = new sharks(new Vector2(1100, 50),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlackBall"));
            sharks.Add(s);
            s = new sharks(new Vector2(950, 170),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlackBall"));
            sharks.Add(s);
            s = new sharks(new Vector2(300, 350),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlackBall"));
            sharks.Add(s);

            messageFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("messageFont");

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            //----------This gets the time value---------
            float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

            //--------------keyboard input---------------
            //Exit
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                this.Exit();
            //Save
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
                Save("test.txt");
            //Load
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.L))
                Load("test.txt");

            //Directional Movement
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
                c.velocity.X = -350;

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
                c.velocity.X = 350;

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
                c.velocity.Y = 350;

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
                c.velocity.Y = -350;


            //UPDATING PLAYING STATE
            switch (gameState)
            {
                case State.Playing:
                    c.Update(elapsed);
                    foreach (Sprite cr in crew)
                    {
                        cr.Update(elapsed);
                    }
                    c.col = Color.White;

                    //----sharks intersects with whiteball----
                    foreach (sharks s in sharks)
                    {
                        if (c.bounds.Intersects(s.bounds))
                        {
                            gameState = State.Gameover;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (sharks s in sharks)
                    {
                        s.Update(elapsed, c.location);
                    }



                    hud.Update(gameTime);
                    //----sprites intersect with whiteball----
                    foreach (Sprite crew1 in crew)
                    {
                        if (c.bounds.Intersects(crew1.bounds))
                        {
                            //gameState = State.Gameover;
                            playerScore += 1;
                            crew1.bounds.X = 1000000;
                            crew1.bounds.Y = 1000000;
                            crew1.location.Y = 1000000;
                            crew1.location.X = 1000000;
                            break;
                        }
                    } break;


                //UPDATING MENU STATE
                case State.Menu:
                    {
                        //Get keyboard state
                        KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
                        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
                        {
                            gameState = State.Playing;
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                //UPDATING GAMEOVER STATE
                case State.Gameover:
                    {
                        //Get keyboard state
                        KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
                        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Back))
                        {
                            if (IsHighScore())
                            {
                                hud.highScore = playerScore;
                                SavehighScore("highScore.txt");
                            }
                            playerScore = 0;
                            sharks.Clear();
                            crew.Clear();
                            gameState = State.Menu;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
            }
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This makes the highscore file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filename"></param>
        private void SavehighScore(string filename)
        {
            TextWriter textOut = null;
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(filename))
                    File.Delete(filename);

                textOut = new StreamWriter(filename);
                textOut.WriteLine(hud.highScore);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (textOut != null) textOut.Close();
            }


            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            spriteBatch.Begin();

            switch (gameState)
            {
                //DRAWING PLAYING STATE
                case State.Playing:
                    {
                        spriteBatch.Draw(backgroundTexture, backgroundRectangle,
             Color.White);
                        c.Draw(spriteBatch);
                        //FOR EACH CREW DRAW
                        foreach (Sprite cr in crew)
                        {
                            cr.Draw(spriteBatch);
                        }
                        //FOREACH SHARK DRAW
                        foreach (sharks s in sharks)
                        {
                            s.Draw(spriteBatch);
                        }

                        hud.Draw(spriteBatch);

                        spriteBatch.DrawString(messageFont, playerScore.ToString(),
                new Vector2(200, 0),
                Color.White);

                        //spriteBatch.DrawString(messageFont, highScore.ToString(),
                           // new Vector2(200, 100), Color.White);

                        spriteBatch.DrawString(messageFont, " Player Scores - ",
                            new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White);
                        break;

                        //spriteBatch.DrawString(messageFont, " High Score - ",
                            //new Vector2(200, 200), Color.White);
                        //break;

                    }
                //DRAWING MENU STATE
                case State.Menu:
                    {
                        spriteBatch.Draw(menuImageTexture, menuImageRectange, Color.White);
                        break;
                    }
                //DRAWING GAMEOVER STATE
                case State.Gameover:
                    {
                        spriteBatch.Draw(gameoverImageTexture, gameoverImageRectangle, Color.White);
                        spriteBatch.DrawString(messageFont, "Your Final Score was - "  + playerScore.ToString(),new Vector2 (0,0), Color.White);
                        spriteBatch.DrawString(messageFont, "Your High score - " + hud.highScore.ToString(), new Vector2(0, 100), Color.White);
                        break;
                    }
            }


            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

This is where the error is coming from:

```
private void Load(TextReader textIn)
        {
            foreach (Sprite crew1 in crew)
            {
                crew1.location.X = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
                crew1.location.Y = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
            }
            foreach (sharks enemySprite in sharks)
            {
                enemySprite.location.X = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
                enemySprite.location.Y = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
            }
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

This is my save file (test.txt)

```
640
450
750
200
1216
656
500
600
800
400
1216
656
Shark
1100
50
Shark
950
170
Shark
164.5326
199.6745
```

If you could be of any help of why this is happening, I would be very grateful.
I also have other codes if you need then.
Thank You

Comment: Can you post the input file as well? The error you're getting means that the line it is reading could not be converted to an int.

Comment: 640
450
750
200
1216
656
500
600
800
400
1216
656
Shark
1100
50
Shark
950
170
Shark
164.5326
199.6745
 This is my save file (text.txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as the input stream reads the line "Shark" and tries to convert it to an int, it is failing, because "Shark" can't be converted to an int. You need to account for this in your Load method, or take the lines saying "Shark" out of the input file.

You'll encounter a similar error trying to read `164.5326` and `199.6745`. These strings can't be converted to integers because they are floating-point numbers. Either change your input file to remove the decimal portion of these numbers or use `float.Parse` or `double.Parse` instead.

Comment: Thank You so much, which I had known this before my coursework was in haha, but thank you

Comment: If you not shure about what you trying to convert you can use Double.TryParse().